# Unit Testing EF Core with In Memory and Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.1

Have been trying to leverage EF core in-memory provider with .Net Dependency injection. Modified [original documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) example, to include .Net core in built, dependency injection.

> However having disposed the context, and instantiating again, not able to retrieve the object,
>   back. Could you point out me in right direction.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Find_searches_url()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "LkBlogs")
        .Options;
    ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>((y) => y.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "LkBlogs"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>())
    {
        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/cats" });
        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/catfish" });
        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/dogs" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        var result = context.Blogs.Find(1);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "From same context (which was used for writing, could not retrieve)");
    }

    using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>())
    {
        var result = context.Blogs.Find(1);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "From new context, instantiated with DI could not retrieve");
    }

    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
        var result = context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault();
        //Error: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException: 'Assert.IsNotNull failed. '
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "From new context, instantiated without DI could not retrieve");
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Documentation example:**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Find_searches_url()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Find_searches_url")
                .Options;

            // Insert seed data into the database using one instance of the context
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/cats" });
                context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/catfish" });
                context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/dogs" });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Use a clean instance of the context to run the test
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                var service = new BlogService(context);
                var result = service.Find("cat");
                Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count());
            }
        }
```

**EDIT: 2**
Have tried all service life times, SingleTon, Transient & Scoped. Exception remains same.

**EDIT: 3**
As per @Chris advice, removed usings for Context. Didn't help:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Find_searches_url()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "LkBlogs")
            .Options;
        ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>((y) => y.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "LkBlogs"),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var context = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>();
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog {Url = "http://sample.com/cats"});
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog {Url = "http://sample.com/catfish"});
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog {Url = "http://sample.com/dogs"});
    context.SaveChanges();
    var result = context.Blogs.Find(1);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "From same context (which was used for writing, could not retrieve)");

    var context2 = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>();
    var result2 = context2.Blogs.Find(1);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result2, "From new context, instantiated with DI could not retrieve");

    var context3 = new BloggingContext(options);
    var result3 = context3.Blogs.FirstOrDefault();
    //Error: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException: 'Assert.IsNotNull failed. '
    Assert.IsNotNull(result3, "From new context, instantiated without DI could not retrieve");
}
```

Comment: How long would you *expect* the in-memory database to live? How would it know that your test ended and it should shut down?

Comment: @nvoigt, thanks for trying to help out. If in-memory db can live in the original example having been disposed. (It works, I validated) why not in my `dependency injection` version.

Comment: you are specifying a transient lifetime, have you tried using ServiceLifetime.Singleton instead?

Comment: @Thorgeir, yes, all scopes.

Comment: I guess you should remove your usings. When using DI, you would inject you context in ctor => you would not use using(){}, so perhaps the extensions for setting up you context in services collection are simply not designed for that.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, thanks! Didn't help either, updated Edit-3